# ¿Por qué Eclipse no actualiza repositorio global de Maven?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

Estoy  empezando  a usar Maven en Eclipse Mars 1.0  y  cuando intento actualizar el repositorio global de Maven no me carga (no actualiza), se queda estancado en 0% y nunca  avanza.

La  verdad no se cuál puede ser el problema. Espero me puedan ayudar por favor.

[image: Asi es como se mantiene]

Comment: ¡Hola compatriota! Bienvenido a SOes, no se de Maven pero imagino que puedes empezar verificando tu conexión, mirando los logs, etc.

Comment: ^^  Gracias  ,pero  bueno ya  revise la conexion  y   con otras acutalizaciones me  funciona de manera normal la descarga :c

Comment: Entonces tal vez el problema sean los servidores de Maven, tal vez estén en mantenimiento? Supongo que podrías buscar el estado de sus servidores consultando en Google

Comment: Bueno   desde ayer  estuve haciendo el mismo proceso de actualizar  y nada  ,dudo que sea el Servidor  :(

Comment: puedes tratar de hacer otra instalacion de eclipse, y de esa forma descartar que no tengas algun fichero de configuracion o asi dando la lata y si te funciona la nueva instalacion ya sabes, por donde mirar o seguir con la nueva. Saludos

Comment: ¿Has visto si tienes algún problema de bloqueo de conexión, quizás por el uso de un proxy o firewall (corafuegos)? Y bienvenido a SOes compatriota :)

Comment: yo tambien tengo el mismo problema y no consigo desgargar los repositorios, desactivé firewall, defender, antivirus ... pero no consigo que pase de rebuilding idexes 0%, es como si no consiguiera conectar

Answer (score 1):

Lo siguiente suele solucionar el problema: 
`Unable to update index for central|http://repo1.maven.org/maven2`
(quizas ayude en su caso pues no veo log alguno)

1. `cerrar` >> Eclipse
2. `borrar` >>
   workspace_location/.metadata/.plugins/org.maven.ide.eclipse/nexus
3. `borrar` >>
   workspace_location/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.core/nexus
4. `ir a` >> `Window`>>`Preferences`>>`Maven` activar “Download repository
   index updates on startup”.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

*La imagen es sacada de google image, para que sirva como guia*

5. reiniciar Eclipse.

Info: https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/199939/

Comment: bueno me funciona   :c , igual sigue sin actualizar