# Eclipse no actualiza repositorio global de Maven

Tags: eclipse, maven, dependencias

Tengo el mismo problema que una pregunta creada hace unos años en [stackoverflow](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/2985/por-qu%C3%A9-eclipse-no-actualiza-repositorio-global-de-maven/611979)

He seguido los pasos, pero no actualiza.

Además, intuyo que por culpa de no poder actualizar el repositorio de maven, tampoco me sale  ningún resultado en dependencias :(

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]